# how to make autocommit false work in kafkajs

Tags: apache-kafka, kafkajs

scenario:
im setting autocommit false,
producing 12 messages 
consuming them.. (say from offset 100)
shutting down consumer 
start  a new consumer

in that stage, I expect to the 2nd consumer to read all messages again starting offset 100 (because no committing was done)

but when producing new messages I see that the 2nd consumer starts from the new offset (113) i.e the commit still occurs somehow..

what do I get wrong?

that is my consumer code

```
const { Kafka } = require('kafkajs');
const kafka = new Kafka({
  clientId: 'my-app',
  brokers: ['192.168.14.10:9095']
});
const admin = kafka.admin();
const consumer = kafka.consumer({ groupId: 'test-group' });
const run = async () => {
  // admin
  await admin.connect();
  // Consuming
  await consumer.connect();
  await consumer.subscribe({ topic: 'topic-test2'});
  await consumer.run({
    autoCommit: false,
    eachMessage: async ({ topic, partition, message }) => {
      console.log({
        partition,
        offset: message.offset,
        value: message.value.toString()
      });
      }
    }
  });
};
run().catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 0):

When a new consumer is spawned it will start consuming from fresh offset available it does not store historical data.
If you want to start consuming from start for a consumer you can use this

const consumer = kafka.consumer({
groupId: 'your-group-id',
autoOffsetReset: 'earliest',
});